# Hypothesis in Propositional Calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So using the collection of statements;
"I have tested my app. If I tested my app and it failed the test, I will not try to sell it to customers. If the test was correct then my app failed the test."

I have to make it into atomic sentences (which i've done)

X : I have tested my app

Y : If I tested my app

P : It failed the test

Z : I will not try to sell it to customers

Q : If the test failed the test

V : My app failed the test

And then I have to express the statements in propositional calculus;

Where I'm stuck; I understand that using the connectives in the collection of statements are used to represent the symbols etc. but how would I construct the first sentence?

"I have tested my app" simple enough, but what do I do after that? do i put a bracket? a comma?

It's baffled me!

Comment: `How would I construct the first sentence? (...) "I have tested my app" simple enough.` I don't get what you're asking.

Comment: Well, It's just a full stop after the sentence, no connectives i.e And, or etc.

How would I put it into a propositional calculus equation?

Comment: I see. That's not something you model in Propositional Calculus. You can just write each sentence in a different line on the paper, or something. It's not really relevant. Commas are fine. If $X$ denotes "I have tested my app", if $P$ denotes "The app failed the test" and if $Z$ denotes "I will not try to sell the app to customers". The first sentence is simply $X$, while the second is $(X\land P)\to Z$. Propositional Calculus isn't refined enough to deal with details like "I have tested" and "I tested", or "it" instead of writing "app". Your $Y$ and $Q$ 'statements' have no place here.

Comment: That makes so much sense, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some atomic sentences that you've found are not actually atomic. The actual atomic sentences are the followings.

> $X$ : I have tested my app.
>   $P$ : My app passed the test.
>   $S$ : I will try to sell the app.
>   $C$ : The test was correct.

From these,

> If *I tested my app* and *my app* failed *the test*, then *I will* not *try to sell the app* :
>   $$\Big(X\;\wedge\;\neg P\Big)\implies\neg S$$

and

> If *the test was correct*, then *my app failed the test* :
>   $$C\implies\neg P.$$